# gcc-config: could not run/locate 'avr-gcc-ar'

Tags: gentoo, gcc, arduino

I'm trying to build an arduino sketch, but it fails with error:

> "/usr/bin/avr-gcc-ar" rcs  "/tmp/arduino_build_191139/core/core.a" "/tmp/arduino_build_191139/core/wiring_pulse.S.o"
>   gcc-config: error: could not run/locate 'avr-gcc-ar'
>   exit status 1
>   Error compiling for board Arduino Nano.

I'm using Gentoo with crossdev for avr and Arduino studio to compile.
`avr-g++` version is `avr-gcc (Gentoo 6.4.0-r1 p1.3) 6.4.0`.

`gcc-config`:

> [1] avr-6.4.0 *
>    [2] x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-6.4.0 *

Does anybody know how to deal with this error?

Comment: You need to add avr binaries into PATH environement.

Comment: https://forums.gentoo.org/viewtopic-p-8195220.html?sid=18f2ad1097c37ef5ee4f799cb3d04d4d